# Bitten by division rounding?

Tags: c#, rounding

Why does the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:C0}", 2170/ 20));
```

yield "$109", while doing

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(2170 / 20));
```

gives me 108?

How can I get 2170 / 20 give me 109?

Comment: `String.Format("{0:C0}", 2170/ 20)` gives `$108`

Comment: 217/2 will be 108.5, so as an integer, which way do you want the rounding?

Comment: @SLaks I am sorry, in the code 2170 was represented by a decimal variable.  I'll edit the question

Comment: @James Black, I'd like it to go in the same direction as string.Format("{0:C0}"... goes

Comment: So, do (int)(2170/20+.5), as that will not do any more rounding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you divide to values of integral type, such as `2170` and `20`, the runtime performs an integer division and discards (truncates) the decimal.

If you change one of the operands to a `float`, `double`, or `decimal` (eg, `2170.0 / 20`, or `2170 / 20m`), it will perform a floating-point division, as you would expect.

Therefore, you need to change it to

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(2170.0 / 20));
```

---

## EDIT

Like this:

```
Math.Round(2170m / 20, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: @SLacks That's what I ended up implementing, however, I wanted to know why. Is the issue that String.Format("{0:C0}"... method uses MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero internally?

Comment: First of all, String.Format uses StringBuilder.AppendFormat, which in turn uses the object's override of ToString.  The behavior of that method is observed to be the same as Math.Round when passed MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero.  But the method does not call Math.Round.

Answer (score 0):

Try Math.Round(2170.0 / 20.0)